# C# Interop get Excel cells background from given range

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

How can I get a list of background colors from the specified range of cells?

This is the only solution that I've found, but it returns the background color from a single cell

```
int colorNumber = System.Convert.ToInt32(((Range) worksheet.Cells[rowNumber,columnNumber]).Interior.Color);
Color color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(colorNumber);
```

I would need something like this:

```
int colorNumber = System.Convert.ToInt32(((Range) worksheet.Range[wsEvars.Cells[rowNumberFrom, columnNumberFrom], wsEvars.Cells[rowNumberTo, columnNumberTo]]).Interior.Color);
Color color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(colorNumber);

// After execution colorNumber == 0
```

Is there any other way to do this without having to loop through each row to get the color?

Comment: You could get the entire range as XML and parse that with XDocument to save a lot of interop calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the entire range as XML and parse that with XDocument to save a lot of interop calls. It only loops every individual style (= cell-wide formatting):

```
using NetOffice.ExcelApi.Enums;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Drawing;
using Excel = NetOffice.ExcelApi;

namespace S_43139465
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var app = Excel.Application.GetActiveInstance())
            {
                var range = (Excel.Range)app.Selection;
                var xml = (string)range.get_Value(rangeValueDataType: XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet);

                var colors = XDocument.Parse(xml)
                                      .Descendants().First(n => n.Name.LocalName == "Styles")
                                      .Descendants().Where(n => n.Name.LocalName == "Interior")
                                      .Select(i => i.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName == "Color"))
                                      .Where(a => a != null)
                                      .Select(a => a.Value)
                                      .Distinct()
                                      .Select(s => ColorTranslator.FromHtml(s));

                foreach (var color in colors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(color);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```